# PHP split a string after certain character, but the string length varies

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, substr

I use a radio button that gives me two variables concatenated and I need to separate them later. It gives me a time and a date in a format 11:30pm3, where 3 is the date and 11:30pm is the time. I can split it fine with my function but if the time is one digit, like 7:30pm for example, it throws things off. I can use military time but that's not what I want.Is there a way to change this so it splits the string right after character "m" so it will work for am/pm, regardless of the length of the time being 7:00am or 07:00am. Thanks in advance.

```
$string = $Radio;   //This is the value I get 
$MeetTime = substr("$string", 0, 7); //Gives me 11:30am
$MeetDay  = substr("$string", 7, 2); //Gives me 2
```

Comment: Why don't you pass a full date string through?  PHP can then handle everything for you.

Comment: It's not the real time. I have set up times for available appointments, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its the real time or not.  Its a date + time so why not pass it something PHP will agree with.  Check out the strtotime function, there are plenty of options for how to format the string.  Why not format it correctly once then everything else will play nice, PHP, database datetime fields etc.

Comment: Also, you must be constructing this string somewhere like var str = time+day.  try var d = new Date(); var str = time + ' ' + day + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getYear();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find out where the m is and do your logic on that

if m is at 6 then its a full length one

```
$loc = stripos($string,"m");
```

if its at 5 then it's short so adjust your split

Comment: Love your idea and got it to work. Thanks!! 

$loc = stripos($string,"m");
if ($loc == 5) {          $MeetTime = substr("$string", 0, 6);          $MeetDay  = substr("$string", 6, 2);
}
else {          $MeetTime = substr("$string", 0, 7);         $MeetDay  = substr("$string", 7, 2);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('~^([\\d]{1,2}:[\\d]{1,2}[ap]m)([\\d]+)$~i', trim($string), $Matches)){
    var_dump($Matches); // See what this prints
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$date = '11:30am3';
$date = explode('pm', $date);
if(count($date) <= 2){
$date = explode('am', $date[0]);
}
print_r($date);
```

where $date[1] is the time and $day[0] the date.
But you should use somet other format, I'd recommend timestamps.